# JS Unit Test not appearing in VS 2015 Test Explorer

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, visual-studio-2015, qunit, chutzpah

I am new to JavaScript unit testing. I am trying to test typescript classes and my tests are also written in typescript, which somewhat looks like below:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/qunit/qunit.d.ts" />
import Utility1 = require("../utility");//This is script I want to test.    

test("utility_test",function() {

    ...

    var result = ...;
    var expected = ...;
    equal(result, expected, "Test failed");
})
```

I am using VS 2015 with chutzpah test adapter installed as shown [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/06/01/test-driven-development-with-typescript.aspx). To be clear I have installed this to extension to vs 2015: [Chutzpah Test Runner Context Menu Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/71a4e9bd-f660-448f-bd92-f5a65d39b7f0), and [Chutzpah Test Adapter for the Test Explorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8741f04-bae4-4900-81c7-7c9bfb9ed1fe) and also added [Chutzpah](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chutzpah) NuGet package.

Yet when I build my project, the test doesn't appear in the Test Explorer. And when I tried to run the test from context menu, it fails with this error: `Error: Error: Called start() outside of a test context while already started`.

Can anyone please let me know where I am going wrong?

---

**EDIT**
For the one looking for the solution with require.js, [this here](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/blob/master/Samples/RequireJS/CustomBaseUrl/QUnit/chutzpah.json) worked for me. Now my `Chutzpah.json` looks like below:

```
{
    "Framework": "qunit",
    "CodeCoverageExcludes": [ "*/require.config.js" ],
    "TestHarnessReferenceMode": "AMD",
    "TestHarnessLocationMode": "SettingsFileAdjacent",
    "TypeScriptModuleKind": "AMD",
    "AMDBaseUrl": "",
    "EnableTestFileBatching": true,
    "Compile": {
        "Mode": "External",
        "Extensions": [ ".ts" ],
        "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [ ".d.ts" ]
    },
    "References": [
        { "Path": "require.js" },
        { "Path": "require.config.js" },
    ],
    "Tests": [
        { "Path": "jsTests" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: For anyone coming here with absolutely correctly configured unit-tests that just won't appear on the Test Explorer panel: **run all tests, then restart Visual Studio**. It solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chutzpah no longer bundles the Typescript compiler inside of it (as of version 4). You must tell Chutzpah where to find your generated `.js` files (or/and how to compile them if you want it to).

See [the documentation for the `Compile` setting](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Compile-Setting)
as well as [these code samples](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/tree/master/Samples/Compilation).

Most people will use the external compile mode when working with Visual Studio since VS can compile the `.ts` files for you and you just need to tell Chutzpah where to find them. That will look like this:

```
{
  "Compile": {
    "Mode": "External",
    "Extensions": [".ts"],
    "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [".d.ts"]
   },
  "References": [
    {"Includes": ["*/src/*.ts"], "Excludes": ["*/src/*.d.ts"] }
  ],
  "Tests": [
    { "Includes": ["*/test/*.ts"], "Excludes": ["*/test/*.d.ts"] }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for the reply. I have the exact same issue. Should this config file be created manually? What folder it should be kept? Seems like bit hidden functionality?

Comment: Please see the documentation and examples on the chutzpah github page (https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Chutzpah.json-Settings-File)

Comment: Sorry for late response. [This one](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/blob/master/Samples/RequireJS/CustomBaseUrl/QUnit/chutzpah.json) worked for me. Thanks for your help :)